# UI Scroll does not work on touch Unity

Tags: canvas, scroll, unity-game-engine, panel, unity3d-gui

I am using unity 4.6 and I made a UI scroll panel before yesterday night it is working fine but today it is not working on touch. I don,t know what is happen. I just add a different camera for canvas. Please help me

Thanks

**Update** :
Added screenshot

[image]

Comment: post a screenshot with your inspector and project hierarchy

Comment: You should first fix your errors. May be a script is breaking due to exception.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite hard to answer without more info but I will try.

The only thing I see is: check you content for the scrollrect - I bet you are adding children to the content transform from code, so the content of the scrollrect needs to be updated to.

Comment: But before adding the camera it working fine.   here is my code to instantiate the object in content :  GameObject friendsentry;
    friendsentry=Instantiate(FindRankOnGameOver.instance.friends)as GameObject;
    friendsentry.transform.parent=FindRankOnGameOver.instance.scroolview.transform;

   
   }

Comment: What do you mean by "adding the camera"? Did you change the canvas rendering mode from screen space overlay to camera? Can you explain more this aspect?

Comment: Yes i change the canvas rendering mode from screen space overlay to camera. I did this because i'm getting the problem of changing the order of non-ui gameobject. i'm not able to see the non ui gameobject in game that's why i used the different camera for canvas and change the layer of the canvas's child gameobject.

Comment: I that case, one more question: do you have more canvases in the scene during the existanse of this scrolrect? If yes - it is possible that over canvases UI elements (can be transparent) are overalying the canvas where scrollrect is. Just quessing.

Comment: Yes that is possible, But how can i set the order and non UI gameobject is also not visible. I tried  hard but does not get the result. then I take another canvas to show the scroll panel working

Comment: If you add another canvas be sure to add a Graphic Raycaster too.